# Select a specific element from a list in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have a react js application where I render a list of items. When a user click on an item and after that clicks outside in `console.log(id, "checked id");` I should see only that item where user clicked before.

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Element = ({ id, setId }) => {
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    const condition = e.target.className.includes("test");
    if (!condition) {
      setId(id);
    }
  };

  console.log(id, "checked id");

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
    return () => document.removeEventListener("click", handleClick);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      className={"test"}
      onClick={() => {
        setId(id);
      }}
    >
      hello {id}
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [idSelect, setIdSelect] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {[0, 1, 2].map((el) => {
        return <Element setId={setIdSelect} key={el} id={el} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Basically I should trigger only that element where user previously clicked. EX: user clicks on `hello 0` item and after that clicks outside, in console they should see only `console.log(0, "checked id");`, meaning that only that component is triggered. 
 Issue: at the moment when user click outside, all the components renders, but I need only where user clicked.

demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-einstein-9v1ws?file=/src/App.js:0-821 
 Question: How to solve my issue?

Comment: The console.log will be executed at each rerender of all Elements, do you want it to be executed only for the currently selected one, only when the user clicks outside?.

Comment: @aim97, yes you are right

Answer (score 0):

First you need to move the console.log to the useEffect to control when it will be executed, since you wanted to execute when the document is clicked them do it the clickHandle.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const handleClick = (e) => {
      const condition = e.target.className.includes("test");
      if (!condition && isSelected) {
        console.log(id, "checked id");
        setId(id); // You don't need this, it's already set to current id.
      }
    };

    document.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
    return () => document.removeEventListener("click", handleClick);
  }, [setId, id, isSelected]);
```

To make sure only the selected Element logs to console i added the attribute `isSelected` to handle that.

```js
isSelected={idSelect === el}
```

This should solve the problem, but just to be safe i added `stopPropagation` to the div click to make sure it doesn't trigger the document click.

```js
onClick={(e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    setId(id);
}}
```

You can check this sandbox i modified [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-chihiro-qio4e?file=/src/App.js:556-630).

---

It seems like we have many attributes right, i believe a good solution for that is move the display event to the parent tag, like this.

```js
export default function App() {
  const [idSelect, setIdSelect] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleClick = (e) => {
      console.log(idSelect, "checked id");
    }

    document.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
    return () => document.removeEventListener("click", handleClick);
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {[0, 1, 2].map((el) => {
        return (
          <Element
            setId={setIdSelect}
            key={el}
            id={el}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can also replace `setId` and `id` attributes with a single click event handler like `() => setId(id)`.

---

If you want the function to be executed as well when the selected id changes, you can use `useEffect` like this.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(idSelect, "checked id");
}, [idSelect]);
```

I suggest moving the `console.log(idSelect, "checked id");` to a function and call it at both events.

Comment: it works, but is there a solution for the next scenario: when user clicks on the 3-rd element and after that on the second, also to trigger that function, because in that case the 3-rd and the 2-nd also are different elements, so should be triggered and in this case.

Comment: My edit assumes you moved the handling to the parent as i suggested, it can still work without it, but i'm sure you want to do more than just log to the console in here, so it better be moved.

Comment: basically as a solution, when i have a list of items,and having to do a logic on each element(ex: change an input or make an https request), is better/safer to track al changes in parent element and to track what element(`id`) is changed and to make that request already in parent component. Am i right?

Comment: It's better to have the state in child to reduce rerender, but if the state is **shared** between multiple children, they will all inevitably rerender when it changes, like selectedId here, moving it to the parent is necessary to enable that. There is also [onClickOutside](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-onclickoutside) which I came to learn about later and would also work for your case.

Comment: So, in my case, when in a parent component i `map()` a list of items, and track changes taking into account each `id` of elements, (ex: send a request using `id` of each element), is it better to do the request in parent component or not?

Comment: you are requesting a list of items from the server, and display them, then you will have a request that affects the current selected component: you can use redux to separate the business logic from presentation logic which should be cleaner, but using react `useState` you would move everything to the parent and have it process all the events, by providing the handlers and passing them to the children, if the event needs to be triggered from the child the handler is called from it.